# how to get the rectangle which is containing a bitmap

Tags: java, android

let's say that I loaded a bitmap then, I draw it in the " ondraw(Canvas canvas) " function and I rotated the canvas. Is it possible to get the rectangle containing the bitmap?
I mean, the new left, top , right and bottom according to the new bitmap's position ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

draw your Bitmap using a Matrix, then use this Matrix when calling mapPoints()